# Error implementing a new operator in Tensorflow for float32 and float64

Tags: python, c++, tensorflow

I implemented a custom operator in Tensorflow following [the official instructions](https://www.tensorflow.org/extend/adding_an_op). I used the T template so that my operator would work with inputs of type floats **and doubles**. This is the head of my .cc file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <cfloat>

#include "third_party/eigen3/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/Tensor"
#include "tensorflow/core/framework/op.h"
#include "tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.h"
#include "tensorflow/core/framework/tensor_shape.h"
#include "work_sharder.h"

using namespace tensorflow;
typedef Eigen::ThreadPoolDevice CPUDevice;

REGISTER_OP("NewOp")
    .Attr("T: {float, double}")
    .Attr("attr1: int")
    .Attr("attr2: float")
    .Input("input1: T")
    .Input("input2: T")
    .Output("output: T");



template <typename Device, typename T>
class NewOpOp : public OpKernel {
  public:
    explicit NewOpOp(OpKernelConstruction* context) : OpKernel(context) {
...
};
```

It compiles correctly until it reaches:

```
REGISTER_KERNEL_BUILDER(Name("NewOp").Device(DEVICE_CPU).TypeConstraint<T>("T"), NewOpOp<CPUDevice, T>);
```

The error message says that the Ts inside brackets were not declared in this scope, whereas the T template was explicitely defined at the end of the first block !
If I change this line for this line:

```
REGISTER_KERNEL_BUILDER(Name("NewOp").Device(DEVICE_CPU).TypeConstraint<float>("T"), NewOpOp<CPUDevice, float>);
```

The compilation errors go away but of course it forces the input to be floats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could solve the issue by registering two different kernels for each op (float and double)

```
REGISTER_KERNEL_BUILDER(Name("NewOp").Device(DEVICE_CPU).TypeConstraint<float>("T"), NewOpOp<CPUDevice, float>);
REGISTER_KERNEL_BUILDER(Name("NewOp").Device(DEVICE_CPU).TypeConstraint<double>("T"), NewOpOp<CPUDevice, double>);
```

It is a bit ugly but it works.